# Job 2:1 a certain day or a day

Tags: hebrew, job

The wording in LXX is on a certain day which is nowhere else to be found;

> Again there was a day when the sons of God came to present themselves
> before the Lord, and Satan came also among them to present himself
> before the Lord. **Job 2:1 King James Version (KJV)**

> And it came to pass **on a certain day**, that **the angels of God
> came to stand before the Lord, and the devil came among them** to
> stand before the Lord. **Job 2:1 LXX Brenton**

On a certain day to come and stand before YHWH seems that Satan in Job 2:1 appear for the 3 appointed festivals to stand before YHWH as mentioned in Deut 16:16.Three times a year all your men must appear before the LORD your God [...] Deut 16:16.

Could on a certain day to stand before YHWH relate to one of the appointed feasts?

Comment: Funny enough, the Hebrew does indeed have *hayom*, i.e. definite article + day (both in Job 1:6 and 2:1).

Comment: @LukeSawczak HaYom = The day plus a day I shall do and look on it thanks!

Comment: @LukeSawczak hayom, i.e. definite article + day. I can't see it, can you see it here [Job 2:1](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/job/2-1.htm) [Job 1:6](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/job/1-6.htm)

Comment: 2nd word: הַיּ֔וֹם

Comment: @LukeSawczak Amen HaYom I see, I thought as Kevin that you meant definite article that hayom + day in the text

Comment: @DanielDahlberg Oh, got it, and I see how my sentence could be read wrong :) Yes indeed, I meant ha (the) yom (day)

Answer (score 1):

The-Day הַיּ֔וֹם “Ha-Yom” is distinct in Job אִיּוֹב “Iyov” 2:1 when הַשָּׂטָן Ha-Satan came before יְהֹוָֽה YHVH in Heaven:

> Now [The-Day] came about that the divine beings presented themselves before YHVH. [Ha-Satan] came along with them to present himself before YHVH ( וַיְהִ֣י הַיּ֔וֹם וַיָּבֹ֙אוּ֙ בְּנֵ֣י הָֽאֱלֹהִ֔ים לְהִתְיַצֵּ֖ב עַל־יְהֹוָ֑ה וַיָּבֹ֚א גַם־הַשָּׂטָן֙ בְּתֹכָ֔ם לְהִתְיַצֵּ֖ב עַל־יְהֹוָֽה )

Similar to a distinct י֔וֹם “Yom” (experienced during creation) in Genesis בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית “Bereshit” 1:3 when לָיְלָה night comes before the presence of light.

> “And Elohim called the light - Day, and the darkness He called - Night, and it was evening and it was morning, one day.” ( וַיִּקְרָ֨א אֱלֹהִ֤ים לָאוֹר֙ י֔וֹם וְלַח֖שֶׁךְ קָ֣רָא לָ֑יְלָה וַֽיְהִי־עֶ֥רֶב וַֽיְהִי־בֹ֖קֶר י֥וֹם אֶחָֽד )

If we understand “The-Day” in Job 2:1 in context of Revelation 21:22-25, then The-Day in Heaven never ends since there is no night in the presence of YHVH.

> [Revelation 21:22-25, NASB] 
> “I saw no temple in it, for the Lord God the Almighty and the Lamb are its temple. And the city has no need of the sun or of the moon to shine on it, for the glory of God has illuminated it, and its lamp is the Lamb. The nations will walk by its light, and the kings of the earth will bring their glory into it. In the daytime (for there will be no night there) its gates will never be closed;

Based on Revelation 21 & Job 2, the presence of Ha-Satan before HaShem interrupts The (unending) Day to dinstinguish a moment in Elohim’s timeline when angels noticed night entered Heaven.

Comment: If "The-Day in Heaven never ends" how are they keeping Sabbath and Elohims appointed feast? Does not haven and earth rest on the 7th day? (Genesis 2:2, Exodus 20:11) ... that one day is with the Lord as a thousand years, and a thousand years as one day 2 Pet3:8. I don't like the answer but I like it due to your contribution. Chidah are you a Jew?

Comment: Shabbat (Genesis 2:2, Exodus 20:11) is a remembrance to Rest from work on the earth like Elohim, after HaArets rotates 6-times (6-sunsets) each week. — However the timeline in Heaven is different than on earth, if you accept Revelation 21:22-25 which reveals no sun or moon (no need for solar/lunar calendars) since the Day is constant.

Comment: "However the timeline in Heaven is different than on earth" I agree it's different then on earth, just got the view you meant the time stod stil and didn't evolve to next day. I don't think you should take Rev 21:22-25 literal it will still have days as day 1 - 6 and Sabbath and moedim